# Paypal integration on website

Tags: php, paypal

My need: I want users to click on button and goes to paypal, where they can login or add the credit card details and payment should be get done. In short, I don't want to store credit card info on my website.

I found 'Express Checkout' is a suitable paypal method for the same. Am I right?
Does this method requires return urls on https only or can work with simple urls?

Can anyone help me with tutorial or something for the same?

Thanks for all of your support.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent PHP Class for PayPal IPN I've used countless times, which doesn't require user registration: http://www.micahcarrick.com/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html

Incidentally, IPN lets you set a return URL via PayPal, though with that class you can send a return URL to IPN before the user pays.

If you want a tutorial or more help though you'll need to tell us which language you're using.

Comment: IPN has nothing to do with a return URL. IPN is for the server-to-server notification as sent from PayPal to an IPN script on your server. The return URL is the URL the buyer is redirected to after completing a payment.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most flexible solution that comes without a monthly fee, and is available globally, is PayPal Express Checkout. Express Checkout does not require a https return/cancel URL.

Here is how it works:
Express Checkout is based on three API calls; SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

1. SetExpressCheckout sets up the payment and returns a token.
2. You redirect the buyer to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=TOKEN-HERE, where TOKEN-HERE is the token you received earlier
3. After the buyer has agreed to the payment, he is returned back to your site.
4. You can call GetExpressCheckoutDetails and supply the token as a parameter to get the PAYERID of the buyer.
5. Call DoExpressCheckoutPayment with the token and PAYERID supplied to finalize the payment

Note: If you want to force the 'card details' screen to be displayed initially, and allow buyers to pay without having a PayPal account, ensure you're setting SOLUTIONTYPE to 'Sole' and LANDINGPAGE to 'Billing' in your SetExpressCheckout API request.
In addition, the 'PayPal Account Optional' setting must be switched to 'On' inside the Payment Receiving Preferences of your PayPal Profile.

You can find additional documentation for Express Checkout at https://www.x.com/community/ppx/documentation#ec as well as the SDK's and sample code at https://www.x.com/community/ppx/sdks#NVP